Trying to compile MDX files and return React JSX elements using ESBuild
So im trying to use ESBuild to, during compile time read a bunch of index.mdx files from subfolders in the folder src/content.
What i want to do is:

get all the folder names
parse the frontmatter in the header of each mdxfile
parse the body of the MDX file and return as a JSX.Element (React component)

In the end i wish to return a list of Articles containing objects with the following type structure:
interface Article {
  path: string,
  content: JSX.Element,
  metadata: Metadata
}

interface Metadata {
 // Different metadata params
}

I have written a custom ESBuild plugin:
// Read folder names
const getFolderNamesInDirectory = (dir) => {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).filter((item) => {
    const itemPath = path.join(dir, item);
    return fs.statSync(itemPath).isDirectory();
  });
};

// Helper function to read and parse an MDX file
const parseMDXFile = async (filePath) => {
  const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
  const { data: metadata, content: mdxContent } = matter(content);

  const compiledMdx = await compile(mdxContent, {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkPrism, remarkImages],
    jsx: true,
  });

  return {
    metadata: metadata,
    jsx: String(compiledMdx),
  };
};

// Define the plugin
const ArticlesPlugin = (folder) => ({
  name: 'articles-plugin',
  setup(build) {
    // Read all folder names in the specified directory
    const folders = getFolderNamesInDirectory(folder);
    const articles = [];

    // Read and parse each index.mdx file
    folders.forEach(async (folderName) => {
      const mdxFilePath = path.join(folder, folderName, 'index.mdx');
      if (fs.existsSync(mdxFilePath)) {
        const { metadata, jsx } = await parseMDXFile(mdxFilePath);

        articles.push({
          path: folderName,
          componentCode: `
            import React from 'react';
            ${jsx}
            export default MDXContent;
          `,
          metadata: metadata,
        });
      }
    });

    // Create a virtual module exporting the articles array
    build.onResolve({ filter: /^virtual:articles$/ }, (args) => {
      console.log(args);
      return { path: args.path, namespace: 'virtual' };
    });

    build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/, namespace: 'virtual' }, (args) => {
      if (args.path === 'virtual:articles') {
          const contents = `
            import React from 'react';
            export const articles = {
              ${articles.map((article) => `path: '${article.path}', article: () => { ${article.componentCode} }, metadata: ${article.metadata}` ).join(',\n')}
            };
          `;
        return {
          contents,
          loader: 'jsx',
        };
      }
    });
  },
});

The problem im having with the above code is that im getting the following build error when running my esbuild build script:
✘ [ERROR] Unexpected "React"

    virtual:virtual:articles:5:19:
      5 │             import React from 'react';

I have a had quite the hard time to understand what type of content a ESBuild plugin should return. It was my understanding that i could return content as a correctly formatted React module.
If i remove the import React from 'react' and remove the jsx: true flag on the mdx compiler i get a different error:
✘ [ERROR] Expected "(" but found "{"

    virtual:virtual:articles:4:19:
      4 │             import {Fragment as _Fragment, jsx as _jsx, jsxs as _jsxs} from "react/jsx-runtime";
        │                    ^
        ╵  

I have sort of understood that the code the compiler generates is a module exporting a MDXContent object i have a feeling that i somehow need to maybe write a bunch of files with the modules in them, then import all these modules in a different file that exports a list containing all the imports.
But im open to any suggestions at this point.
I have spent a lot of time reading the ESBuild plugin documentation and the MDXCompiler docs and i feel im getting really close, but its this last part that is giving me a rough time.
So how do i return React components from an ESBuild plugin as a list so i can import them as a list in my react code.
